# jQuery/js preventing duplicate checkbox to appear using multiselect widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**Background/Currently**

I'm using Eric Hynds jQuery MultiSelect Widget that is being populated from a javascript file. In my fiddle, the user is only allowed to check 2 options between both widgets. Once the user selects an option, a dynamic checkbox with value is attached to a Main if the corresponding Main is checked. The user is also able to either check Main or an option first and still dynamically show up under the corresponding Main.

**Issue** If Option1 is already added under a checked Main1, checking Main2 will also add a duplicate to Main1. Please see my fiddle of how it works and issue I'm trying to fix. http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/94/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".multiselect").multiselect({
        header: "Choose up to 5 areas total",
        click: function (event, ui) {
             var number1=$("#MDCselect").children(":checked").length,
                number2=$("#Clinicalselect").children(":checked").length;

            if (ui.checked && ((number1 + number2 >=2) || $(this).children(":checked").length >= 2)) {
                return false;
            }

            var lbl = ui.value;
            if(ui.checked){
                var ctrl = '<input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked="checked" class="chk" id="'+lbl+'">';
                $("[id^=id]:checked").each(function(){
                    $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').append('<div>'+ctrl+lbl+'</div>');    
                });
            }
            else {
                $("[id^=id]:checked").each(function(){
                    $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').find('#' + lbl).parent().remove();
                })
            }
        },
        selectedList:5
    });
    $(".checkers").click(function() {        
        if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).nextAll('.holder:eq(0)').find('div input').parent().remove();
        }
        else {
            var checkedOnes = $('#MDCselect').nextAll('.ui-multiselect-menu').find('ul li input:checked');
            for(var i = 0; i < checkedOnes.length; i++) {
                var lbl = checkedOnes.eq(i).attr('value');
                var ctrl = '<input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked="checked" class="chk" id="'+lbl+'">';
                $("[id^=id]:checked").each(function(){
                    $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').append('<div>'+ctrl+lbl+'</div>');    
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
$(".holder").html(""); // Added to line #31
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/b2CsB/